# How fast is Skyreach Castle?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures

**WARNING, Hoard of the Dragon Queen Spoilers!**

In Episode 8: Castle in the Clouds,

> the players get a chance to commandeer Skyreach Castle.

One of the commands is for the castle to move in a cardinal direction, but it doesn't state how fast it moves.

I know it's less than 80ft, because

> the sidebar on **Wyvern Riding and Castle Catching** says:
>
>  *Wyverns are faster than the castle in flight, and they can catch up to it.*

And that it is at least 10ft, because

> It can *Rise* and *Sink* at a rate of 10 feet per round.

For reasons, I need the exact speed of the castle, whether it is written somewhere in the jumbled module, or there's guidance from a different module (maybe Storm King's Thunder?), or if you've personally ruled a particular speed (if you did, please tell me how it went!).

Hurry, the PCs are catching up.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/dndnext/comments/6v3h1b/hotdq_overland_speed_of_skyreach_castle/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Storm King's Thunder, the players get the chance (*early on*) to ride in a storm giant's flying tower. They list the following flight times from Nightstone. I cross-referenced with some measurements on [this map](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/535pq8/ocmap_faerun_sword_coast_merge_of_scag_skt/).

- Bryn Shander => 624 hours for ~625 miles
- Goldenfields => 72 hours for ~70 miles
- Triboar => 275 hours for ~275 miles

Without splitting pixels, that's roughly 1 mile per hour. Punching that in to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%20mile%20per%20hour%20in%20feet%20per%20second)%20*%206%20seconds), we get **8.8ft / round**. You suspect that it goes *at least 10ft / round* because of the description for vertical flying, but I would propose that 10ft / round is really the flying speed for *any* direction.

So this isn't perfect, this is a cloud giant *tower* instead of a cloud giant *castle*. But I don't have any reason to believe that the castle moves at some significantly different pace.

For all intents and purposes, the flying castle is moving slower than most flying things, especially over short distances. It's not going to race anything over the short term. However, it can be kept moving for 24 hours / day which means it is moving as fast as humans over land.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no canonical speed given.

The upper limit is actually 160 feet per turn because the creatures that are pursuing can take an action each round to Dash which the castle cannot do.

When I DMed it, the speed of the castle was not important "for [different] reasons".

I suggest you look to your "reasons" and make a ruling which will provide an interesting but achievable challenge for your players - after all, that's what you're there for.